# How to connect a specific Customer object with its own Account objects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, composition

I'm trying to program a banking system. This is for a class assignment, so I'm not looking for an entire solution, but just how to accomplish one aspect. The system has a Customer class, an abstract Account class, and 4 derived account classes. I'm using Windows Forms to accept user input. The user types the customer information into text boxes, then clicks a button which instantiates a new customer object and adds it to a list of customers that was created earlier in the code:

```
customerList.Add(new Customer(custID, name, phone));
```

Then the user can enter account information and select the type of account, then click another button to instantiate an account object with a Customer object as one of its parameters.

```
checkingList.Add(new CheckingAccount(_____, acctNum, startBal, "Checking"));
```

Here is the overloaded Account constructor:

```
public Account(Customer customer, int acctNum, decimal balance, string acctType)
        {
            _customer = customer;
            _acctNum = acctNum;
            _balance = balance;
            _APY = APY;
            _acctType = acctType;
        }
```

My problem is, I don't know what should go in the `new CheckingAccount(_____, acctNum, startBal, "Checking")` line in place of the underscores shown here. The idea is to use composition to show that the account belongs to the customer (i.e. the customer "has-an" account), so that I can show a list of accounts belonging to specific customers. This works fine when instantiating objects directly in the code without user input, because I can name the Customer object variable as I write it. For example:

```
Customer customer1 = new Customer(1000, "John Doe", "555-555-5555");
customerList.Add(customer1);
checkingList.Add(new CheckingAccount(customer1, 300001, 5000, "Checking"));
savingsList.Add(new SavingsAccount(customer1, 400001, 10000, "Savings"));
```

In place of the underscores above, I've tried using `custID` and `Customer.custID` but I keep getting the following error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'Bank.Customer'
>   And I understand why the error is popping up, but I can't figure out the correct way so I don't get the error.

Another idea I've thought about but can't quite figure out how to implement is simply eliminating the Customer object from the parameter list in the overloaded constructor. Instead, to call an account of a specific customer, I would use the objects index in the list. But, other than just knowing the order in which customers/accounts were added to their respective lists, how would the user be able to pull up the right information for the right customer/account?

Comment: Provide us more code to work with by specifying first of all what your lists are and leaving only the minimal code required to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your issue is that you're having trouble going from given user input in your Windows Form to creating an account? It seems like you've already got the gist of what to put in your _____ blocks with your "instantiating directly in the code" section.

I'd recommend that, for your form that creates a new account, have a dropdown of Customers populated from the customerList.  Then, map the user's selection to the actual Customer in the customerList by id, and pass it into the account constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what I was looking for, but it got the job done well enough. I modified my constructor to accept a string called `custID` instead of an instantiation of the actual customer object. I also added a string field of the same name to my abstract Account class as well as a List field called `List<Account> _accountList;`

Then in my main program, I added all derived account objects to the List. To call an account belonging to a specific customer, I used the following loop and if-statement:

```
private void btnShowCustAccts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstbxAccounts.Items.Clear();
    string currentCustomer = txtbxEnterCustID.Text;
    for (int i=0; i< accountList.Count;i++)
    {
        if (accountList[i].CustID == currentCustomer)
            lstbxAccounts.Items.Add(accountList[i]);
    }
}
```

Of course I would want something more robust for an actual banking system, but this was good enough for class!